# how to Convert JSON data Object into Highcharts Series data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have some JSON Data object and its needs to convert into Highcharts Series data, I tried lot with my minimal knowledge in JS, but i can't,

Json Object :

```
[
    {
        "actionId": "fd799109-7cfd-489b-acce-28e2b538258e",
        "actionName": "Stand",
        "withInteraction": 1.4,
        "withoutInteraction": 1.2,
        "knee": 2.4,
        "arm": 2.3,
        "trunk": 0,
        "leg": 0,
        "neck": 2
    },
    {
        "actionId": "a64eee9f-3b71-4335-a4cd-b62cf1e4e270",
        "actionName": "Walk",
        "withInteraction": 1.4,
        "withoutInteraction": 1.2,
        "knee": 2.4,
        "arm": 2.3,
        "trunk": 0,
        "leg": null,
        "neck": null
    },
    {
        "actionId": "9ca31804-0084-4bd5-8bfc-32f8a99c1c22",
        "actionName": "Bend",
        "withInteraction": 2.4,
        "withoutInteraction": 2.7,
        "knee": 2.4,
        "arm": 2.3,
        "trunk": 0,
        "leg": 0,
        "neck": 2
    },
    {
        "actionId": "08f4d687-436b-4faa-9d4f-0c4fe77f7ac7",
        "actionName": "Move",
        "withInteraction": 1.4,
        "withoutInteraction": 1.2,
        "knee": 2.4,
        "arm": 2.3,
        "trunk": 0,
        "leg": 0,
        "neck": 2
    }
]
```

The above data needs to be converted to be like below

```
series: [
    {
      name: 'knee',
      data: [2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4],
      color : '#78e08f'
    }, {
      name: 'leg',
      data: [0,null,0,0],
      color : '#c23616'
    },
{...}
]
```

Please help me out to fix this , Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `Json Object` - no, that's either JSON or a Javscript Object

Comment: How you get colour data?

Comment: color is not mandate, its optional only,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create arrays of the data series names (by getting all the keys from the first object which are data values) and the colours that you want to assign to those series, you can then iterate the keys and filter the required data out of the returned json data (which I have assumed you have parsed to a JavaScript object):

```js
const keys = Object.keys(jsondata[0]).filter(k => !["actionId", "actionName"].includes(k))

const colours = keys.map((_) => `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffffff).toString(16)}`)

const result = {
  series: keys.map((key, i) => ({
    name: key,
    data: jsondata.map(o => o[key]),
    color: colours[i]
  }))
}

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  const jsondata = [{
      "actionId": "fd799109-7cfd-489b-acce-28e2b538258e",
      "actionName": "Stand",
      "withInteraction": 1.4,
      "withoutInteraction": 1.2,
      "knee": 2.4,
      "arm": 2.3,
      "trunk": 0,
      "leg": 0,
      "neck": 2
    },
    {
      "actionId": "a64eee9f-3b71-4335-a4cd-b62cf1e4e270",
      "actionName": "Walk",
      "withInteraction": 1.4,
      "withoutInteraction": 1.2,
      "knee": 2.4,
      "arm": 2.3,
      "trunk": 0,
      "leg": null,
      "neck": null
    },
    {
      "actionId": "9ca31804-0084-4bd5-8bfc-32f8a99c1c22",
      "actionName": "Bend",
      "withInteraction": 2.4,
      "withoutInteraction": 2.7,
      "knee": 2.4,
      "arm": 2.3,
      "trunk": 0,
      "leg": 0,
      "neck": 2
    },
    {
      "actionId": "08f4d687-436b-4faa-9d4f-0c4fe77f7ac7",
      "actionName": "Move",
      "withInteraction": 1.4,
      "withoutInteraction": 1.2,
      "knee": 2.4,
      "arm": 2.3,
      "trunk": 0,
      "leg": 0,
      "neck": 2
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Nick , the key values in some cases not same, its dynamic, its subject to change

Comment: @Sathishkumar are there fixed keys in each object that you will *not* process?

Comment: yes, actionName and actionId are fixed, maybe in future hand or head can be added instead of any other key

Comment: @Sathishkumar please see my edit, that should work for dynamic keys

Comment: Aweeeesome !!!  @Nick Thanks a lot,  It's working as expected.

Comment: @Sathishkumar good to hear. I'm glad I could help

Comment: Hi @Nick, I've some issues on showing data into charts, I need to show all cycle time for PID in same column is that possible?

Comment: @Sathishkumar I'm not sure exactly what you mean? It might be easier to ask a new question; you can refer back to this one if needed for context.

Comment: Hi @Nick please look out this new questions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73578429/how-to-create-custom-json-object-for-highcharts-series

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash grouping approach, with logical nullish assignment [(??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const data = [{"actionId":"fd799109-7cfd-489b-acce-28e2b538258e","actionName":"Stand","withInteraction":1.4,"withoutInteraction":1.2,"knee":2.4,"arm":2.3,"trunk":0,"leg":0,"neck":2},{"actionId":"a64eee9f-3b71-4335-a4cd-b62cf1e4e270","actionName":"Walk","withInteraction":1.4,"withoutInteraction":1.2,"knee":2.4,"arm":2.3,"trunk":0,"leg":null,"neck":null},{"actionId":"9ca31804-0084-4bd5-8bfc-32f8a99c1c22","actionName":"Bend","withInteraction":2.4,"withoutInteraction":2.7,"knee":2.4,"arm":2.3,"trunk":0,"leg":0,"neck":2},{"actionId":"08f4d687-436b-4faa-9d4f-0c4fe77f7ac7","actionName":"Move","withInteraction":1.4,"withoutInteraction":1.2,"knee":2.4,"arm":2.3,"trunk":0,"leg":0,"neck":2}];

const reservedlKeys = ["actionId","actionName"];

const getColor = (key) => '#000000';

const groups = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (!reservedlKeys.includes(key)) {
        acc[key] ??= { name: key, data: [], color: getColor(key) };
        acc[key].data.push(value);
      }
    });
    return acc;
}, {});

const series = Object.values(groups);

console.log(series)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```