# how to create custom object for Highcharts series

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I have a custom data to show in Highcharts column stack chart, please look below data and code

```
var data = [
        {
            "personId": "ff6b9c90-3961-4995-b05c-eaa8c0689f7c",
            "pid": "PID-2",
            "averageCycleTime": 3.216666666666667,
            "idealCycleTime": 5,
            "cycleDetails": [
                {
                    "cycleId": "4019551e-b6b8-45cb-8df6-1c8c3c9d8995",
                    "visionCycleId": "1",
                    "cycleDuration": 4.433333333333334,
                    "actionDetails": null
                },
                {
                    "cycleId": "de3203bc-9a82-4aaa-a448-ea83d51793e1",
                    "visionCycleId": "2",
                    "cycleDuration": 3.7333333333333334,
                    "actionDetails": null
                },
                {
                    "cycleId": "7418d534-4159-4f0c-8dbe-3271dcf16f24",
                    "visionCycleId": "3",
                    "cycleDuration": 3.7333333333333334,
                    "actionDetails": null
                },
                {
                    "cycleId": "066cc343-7924-4c9e-86df-f062f9987183",
                    "visionCycleId": "0",
                    "cycleDuration": 0.9666666666666667,
                    "actionDetails": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "personId": "6ce9ac4d-f32b-468e-809a-24ae51e00544",
            "pid": "PID-3",
            "averageCycleTime": 0.26666666666666666,
            "idealCycleTime": 5,
            "cycleDetails": [
                {
                    "cycleId": "55aab433-b2d8-4e62-a40b-d6b15610fc37",
                    "visionCycleId": "0",
                    "cycleDuration": 0.26666666666666666,
                    "actionDetails": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "personId": "d7a4362f-07f9-4e64-9ccb-be8d0a194c61",
            "pid": "PID-4",
            "averageCycleTime": 4.133333333333333,
            "idealCycleTime": 5,
            "cycleDetails": [
                {
                    "cycleId": "c664f6ce-a1fd-4d44-96f6-0236181fd784",
                    "visionCycleId": "1",
                    "cycleDuration": 3.8333333333333335,
                    "actionDetails": null
                },
                {
                    "cycleId": "fc53a523-9d32-40ea-af3d-957122fb979e",
                    "visionCycleId": "2",
                    "cycleDuration": 3.8,
                    "actionDetails": null
                },
                {
                    "cycleId": "791666d3-b1f9-4bcf-ad13-8639bfd2ead9",
                    "visionCycleId": "0",
                    "cycleDuration": 4.766666666666667,
                    "actionDetails": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

from this im using below javascript code to convert into highcharts series data

```
let sortedArray : any;
     sortedArray =  data.sort((a : any,b : any)=> a.pid.localeCompare(b.pid));
let personIDList = sortedArray.map((pItems : any,idx : any)=> pItems.pid);
    const series = customJson.map((value, key) => {
      return {
        name: `Cycle-${key + 1}`,
        data: value.cycleDetails.map((v) => ({
          y: v.cycleDuration,
          videoId: v.cycleId,
        })),
      };
    });
```

in the above, I sorted the array based on PID and then extract the PID for setting up Category.
Below is chart configurations, Check the chart configurations with data

```
{
        chart: {
          type: 'column'
        },
        title: false,
        xAxis: {
            categories: this.personIDList,
            labels :{
              style : {
                color : '#1e272e',
                cursor : 'pointer'
              }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Cycle Time (Sec\'s)'
            },
            gridLineWidth : 1,
            gridLineColor : '#f5f6fa',
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'gray',
                    textOutline: 'none'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'center',        
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',        
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointWidth : 30,
                borderRadius : 8,
                stacking : 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            },
            series : {
              point: {
                events: {
                  click: function(this : any){                               
                                              
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        },
        series: series
      }
```

With above code my result is

[image]

in this picture Blue color bars are related to PID-2 but here all data is shuffled with all PID.
I need to show all PID details in the same column based on the PID name.

my expected data chart should be

[image]

Comment: What you're doing seems reasonable, we probably need to see the rest of the chart structure you're passing to highcharts to figure out the issue.

Comment: Hi @nick please check my edits

Comment: Is that possible @Nick ??

Comment: Probably but I'm afraid it's beyond my highcharts knowledge... sorry!

Comment: @Nick, What if change the format of the series for achieving this?

Comment: How do you expect to get a graph in your drawing when there's data missing? `PID-3` only has one value

Comment: @KScandrett if there is no data it should be 0

Comment: Hi @Nick can you please look out for the ppotaczek answer? and there is one issue, I found the issue, and need your help to resolve that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result you want by first extracting all the raw data from your input into a nested object with top-level keys of `visionCycleId` and lower level keys of `pid` (this is called `rawData` in the snippet). This can then be post-processed using the list of `pid` values to generate the data arrays for charting:

```js
data.sort((a, b) => a.pid.localeCompare(b.pid))

const personIDList = data.map(({ pid }) => pid);

// get the data
const rawData = data.reduce((acc, { pid, cycleDetails }) => {
  cycleDetails.forEach(({ visionCycleId, cycleDuration }) => 
    acc[visionCycleId] = Object.assign(acc[visionCycleId] || {}, { [pid] : cycleDuration }))
  return acc
}, {})

const series = Object.entries(rawData)
  .map(([k, v]) => ({
    name: `Cycle-${k}`,
    data: personIDList.map(pid => v[pid] || 0)
  }))

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: personIDList
  },
  yAxis: {
    reversedStacks: false
  },
  accessibility: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
  var data = [{
      "personId": "ff6b9c90-3961-4995-b05c-eaa8c0689f7c",
      "pid": "PID-2",
      "averageCycleTime": 3.216666666666667,
      "idealCycleTime": 5,
      "cycleDetails": [{
          "cycleId": "4019551e-b6b8-45cb-8df6-1c8c3c9d8995",
          "visionCycleId": "1",
          "cycleDuration": 4.433333333333334,
          "actionDetails": null
        },
        {
          "cycleId": "de3203bc-9a82-4aaa-a448-ea83d51793e1",
          "visionCycleId": "2",
          "cycleDuration": 3.7333333333333334,
          "actionDetails": null
        },
        {
          "cycleId": "7418d534-4159-4f0c-8dbe-3271dcf16f24",
          "visionCycleId": "3",
          "cycleDuration": 3.7333333333333334,
          "actionDetails": null
        },
        {
          "cycleId": "066cc343-7924-4c9e-86df-f062f9987183",
          "visionCycleId": "0",
          "cycleDuration": 0.9666666666666667,
          "actionDetails": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "personId": "6ce9ac4d-f32b-468e-809a-24ae51e00544",
      "pid": "PID-3",
      "averageCycleTime": 0.26666666666666666,
      "idealCycleTime": 5,
      "cycleDetails": [{
        "cycleId": "55aab433-b2d8-4e62-a40b-d6b15610fc37",
        "visionCycleId": "0",
        "cycleDuration": 0.26666666666666666,
        "actionDetails": null
      }]
    },
    {
      "personId": "d7a4362f-07f9-4e64-9ccb-be8d0a194c61",
      "pid": "PID-4",
      "averageCycleTime": 4.133333333333333,
      "idealCycleTime": 5,
      "cycleDetails": [{
          "cycleId": "c664f6ce-a1fd-4d44-96f6-0236181fd784",
          "visionCycleId": "1",
          "cycleDuration": 3.8333333333333335,
          "actionDetails": null
        },
        {
          "cycleId": "fc53a523-9d32-40ea-af3d-957122fb979e",
          "visionCycleId": "2",
          "cycleDuration": 3.8,
          "actionDetails": null
        },
        {
          "cycleId": "791666d3-b1f9-4bcf-ad13-8639bfd2ead9",
          "visionCycleId": "0",
          "cycleDuration": 4.766666666666667,
          "actionDetails": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and knowledge. It's working as expected. Your effort is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build series structure required by Highcharts. For example:

```
const sortedArray = data.sort((a, b) => a.pid.localeCompare(b.pid));
const personIDList = sortedArray.map((pItems, idx) => pItems.pid);

const series = [];

sortedArray.forEach((pid, pidIndex) => {
    pid.cycleDetails.sort((a, b) => a.visionCycleId.localeCompare(b.visionCycleId));
    pid.cycleDetails.forEach((cycle, index) => {
        if (series[index]) {
            series[index].data.push([pidIndex, cycle.cycleDuration]);
        } else {
            series.push({
                name: 'Cycle-' + cycle.visionCycleId,
                data: [
                    [pidIndex, cycle.cycleDuration]
                ]
            });
        }
    });
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: personIDList
    },
    yAxis: {
        reversedStacks: false
    },
    series
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2xqncjzw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.reversedStacks

Comment: Thanks for the help, One issue is On PID-3 there is only one cycleDetails but on processed data, it will shows 3 items, can you check

Comment: I think we should add 0 for not available cycle details for each PID, I also looked at how to achieve this, and please you also look for the same.

Comment: @Sathishkumar making the values 0 will have no effect on the chart.

Comment: @Nick , Yes I know but problem is on above example PID-3 has only one cycle details when we try to add that data series index other pid values also added with that, please look at js fiddle example

Comment: @Sathishkumar I looked at the fiddle. It seems to work fine. I'm not sure what you mean by "when we try to add that data series index other pid values also added with that"

Comment: @Nick in the sample data PID-3 has only one cycle details but on chart it shows 3 instead of 1, it's added the PID-4 values with pid-3

Comment: Hi @Sathishkumar, Thanks for the explanation. We need to set series data in `[x, y] format`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2xqncjzw/